# Can translation languages be activated/deactivated with the Metadata API?

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, translation, translation-workbench

For existing translation languages, some of them can have an inactive status as below:

[image]

There is a [Translations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.230.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_translations.htm) Metadata Type that doesn't have any Status or IsActive tag. At first deployment, any new language will be set as active, but for existing language with inactive status, status won't change to active again after deployment.

There is also a [Translation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_translation.htm) object that can be updated easily via Apex or SFDX CLI for instance, but I would like to have the language status versioned, and reflected via PULL command when changed in the UI.

I'm afraid the answer will be "NO" for now as there is no specific tag in the related Metadata Type, but asking in case I missed something here.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the answer is No, you cannot make Status as active/inactive on translation workbench using Metadata API.

[image]

Check similar details [here](https://albasfdc.com/2018/10/30/working-with-translation-workbench-programmatically/).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to update one of the language status from active to inactive from salesforce inspector(salesforce chrome plugin) which internally use metadata api to update the records and it updated successfully.
[image]